# Getting Forcetk to work - "GET Error net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND" while using query

Tags: callout, chrome, forcetk

I am trying to create a simple Chrome extension plugin with forcetk to query on data.

My manifest json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "GTmetrix Analyzer Plugin",
  "description": "This extension will analyze a page using GTmetrix",
  "version": "1.0",
  "page_action": {
   "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.salesforce.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-1.12.1.min.js","contentscript.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
   "cookies","tabs", "*://*.salesforce.com/*"
   ],
   "background": {
    "page": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

a Background page -

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="forcetk.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

My JS script using forcetk  -

```
var client = new forcetk.Client();

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log('in mail lisener');
    if (request.type == "getSessionId"){
      getUrls(request, sender, sendResponse);
      return true;
    }
});

function getUrls(request, sender, sendResponse){
  var resp = sendResponse;
  chrome.cookies.get({url: "https://ap1.salesforce.com", name: "sid"}, function(cookies){
      resp({sessionId : cookies.value});
      client.setSessionToken(cookies.value);
      client.query("SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1", function(response){
        console.log('acc rsponse -->' + response.records[0].Name);
      });

  });
}
```

NOw if you check the above code I get an error on client.query method callout.

Complete error

> GET chrome-extension://kjgchmfecdjnlkgfojkdpbfpneccmaad/services/data/v29.0/query?q=SELECT%20Id%20FROM%20Account%20LIMIT%201&_=1456768987075 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I m not sure how to use forcetk here. Any help will be very helpful

Thanks,
Ray

Comment: I got it solved guys, I was making the callout in backgroud js rather than content script, also needed to add forcetk to manifest file so that content script can work proeprly,. Thanks anyways guys..!!!